# How can I deny access for non-authorized users to any web page

Tags: spring, security

I'm using Spring Security and I'd like to deny access for any non-authorized user to any web-page except the login-page. Is it possible to do without specifying `<intercept-url>` tag for any web-page? `intercept-url` is non-flexible solution in that case. We should update the spring-security configuration any time we add a new web-page. Maybe there is something more flexible than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcards to intercept the URL's that you don't specify explicitly:

e.g.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```